Short story in which the protagonist shrinks to the size of his model train set and is run over by one of his trains
I read this in the very early 80's. It was in an SF collection which I suspect was from the UK, but I could be mistaken.
It involves a protagonist who obsessively plays with his model railway. One night, he shrinks to the size of the model railway, where he is eventually run over by one of his trains.
The chatbots are hallucinating all sorts of nonsense. Can anyone help, please?

Do you recall if the protagonist was a child or an adult?

I might remember this one... the protagonist has a son who he doesn't allow to touch the trains, and it turns out the son is the one running the train that hits him. I want to say it's from a Hitchcock anthology.

If someone posts a correct answer, you can accept by clicking on the checkmark by the voting buttons, as per the [tour].

This might be "The Attic Express" by Alex Hamilton. Summary from here.

Model-train mad Hector Coley can't understand why his son isn't as enthusiastic as he about the massive model train set he has put together. When he find himself shrunk to tiny size and on the layout it's full steam ahead as his little boy takes hold of the controls.

One of the things that struck me about the story, when I read it as a kid in Alfred Hitchcock's Supernatural Tales of Terror and Suspense, was that it pointed out how different things felt at a smaller scale.

Also https://archive.org/details/alfredhitchsup00hitc/page/n1/mode/2up
